# CSV reader not reading entire file

Tags: python, file, csv

I have looked at previous answers to this question, but in each of those scenarios the questioners were asking about something specific they were doing with the file, but the problem occurs for me even when I am not.

I have a .csv file of 27,204 rows. When I open the python interpreter:

```
python
import csv
o = open('btc_usd1hour.csv','r')
p = csv.reader(o)
for row in p:
  print(row)
```

I then only see roughly the last third of the document displayed to me.

Comment: What do you get if you try `len(p)`

Comment: try `print(sum(1 for _ in p))` instead of your loop, because your code works fine here.

Comment: Is it possible, that's the maximum buffer in your console display window?

Comment: @Darkstarone I was guessing the same

Comment: @Darkstarone This is not the case, because in the application I am using which maps the CSV file to an implementation within the program, at a certain point it goes blank, just like the print(). In addition, with the print() it starts from around the last third of the file, so if it was the buffer I would assume it'd start from the beginning at least.

Comment: @alec_djinn len(p) gives: TypeError: object of type '_csv.reader' has no len()

Comment: @EthanKershner p is probably an iterator, maybe `len(list(p))` will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try so, at me works:

```html
             with open(name) as csvfile:
                reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
                for row in reader:
                  print(row)
```

reference:

https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader read here :)

Comment: `csv DictReader` calls the `csv.reader` internally and does more things. One of them is skipping empty lines. So, it could also be that this usage actually masked some errors. For Python 2, the file should be open in binary mode. For Python 3 it should add `newline=''`. It makes a difference when the csv file contains strings and when newlines or tabulators can be inside of the strings.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code

```
import csv

fname = 'btc_usd1hour.csv'
with open(fname, newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

It is difficult to tell what is the problem without having the sample. I guess the problem would be removed if you add that `newline=''` for opening the file.

Use the `with` construct to close the file automatically. Use the `f` name for *a file object* when no further explanation is needed. Store the file name to `fname` to make future modifications easier (and also for easy copying the code fragment for your later programs).

olisch may be right that the console just scrolled so fast you could not see the result. You can write the result to another text file like this:

```
with open(fname, newline='') as fin,\
     open('output.txt', 'w') as fout:
    reader = csv.reader(fin)
    for row in reader:
        fout.write(repr(row) + '\n')
```

The `repr` function converts the `row` list into its string *representation*. The `print` calls that function internally, so you will have the same result that you otherwise observe on screen.

Comment: When I run this code I get: 

' 'newline' is an invalid keyword argument for this function'

Comment: This is for Python 3 -- I guesed that because of your print with parentheses. For Python 2, you should `open` in binary mode instead. Like `open(fname, 'rb')`.

Answer (score 0):

maybe your scrollback buffer is just to short to see the whole list?

In general your csv.reader call should be working fine, except your 27k rows aren't extremly long so that you might be able to hit any 64bit boundaries, which would be quite uncommon.

`len(o)` might be interesting to see.